# How to specify x-axis and y-axis input data in dc.js time series graph?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to create a time series graph where my x-axis should be a time and y-axis is speed. Im reading both time and speed values from a json array. I can see many examples in the internet where they have defined only x-axis using crossfilter.
My json (which is input to the graph) looks like below. Only a sample is shown here.

```
   [
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:24:49.000 UTC",
    "Speed": 1.885
  },
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:24:59.000 UTC",
    "Speed": 1.875
  },
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:25:00.000 UTC",
    "Speed": 1.878
  },
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:25:01.000 UTC",
    "Speed": 1.876
  }
]
```

Can someone please suggest how to mark these time in x-axis and speed in y-axis for a time series graph using dc.js

Comment: "Dimension" in crossfilter means "keys you can filter on". So there is no need for a Y dimension in most cases. It's probably not the best choice of terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var cf = crossfilter(data);

var timeDimension = cf.dimension(function(d){ return new Date(d.Time); });
var totalGroup = timeDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d){ return d.Speed; });

var lineChart = dc.lineChart("#line-chart")
    .brushOn(false)
    .width(800)
    .height(200)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return new Date(d.Time);
    })))
    .dimension(timeDimension)
    .group(totalGroup);

dc.renderAll();
```

Check [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cp4dpfry/2/).  (There are strange ticks on x-axis, because of we have very closest dates in dataset that you provide. With full dataset it will [look like this](http://jsfiddle.net/cp4dpfry/3/)).

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I would like to do same using dc.js. The syntax seems to be very different there. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: @user3754877 Oh, I mixed up c3.js with dc.js firstly. I updated the answer, check, please.